# Parameterization removes escape character from JSON POST request and gives Bad request error 400 in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter, bad-request

JMeter script recording capture JSON post request with three escape character(\) and rerun as it is without parameterization it works fine. 
But if we use any Variable "${xyz}" anywhere in the request body and run in JMeter, all the three slashes(\) becomes two slashes(\) while passing the request to application.
Then the request failed as "BAD Request" as application doesn't accept request with two slashes.

I have already tried "FileToString" method but no success.

```
 "Draft":{
"id": 123654656,
"draftdata":{\\\"accCat\\\":\\\"207\\\",\\\"accNumber\\\":\\\"656565
\\\",\\\"id\\\":${Var_ID},...}
}

 "Draft":{
"id": 123654656,
"draftdata":{\\\"accCat\\\":\\\"207\\\",\\\"accNumber\\\":\\\"656565
\\\",\\\"id\\\":9876,...}
}
```

When i pass request with variable the request becomes like below and can be seen in results tree as request body

```
"Draft":{
"id": 123654656,
"draftdata":{\\"accCat\\":\\"207\\",\\"accNumber\\":\\"656565
\\",\\"id\\":${Var_ID},...}
```

But without parameterization variable it works perfectly as request goes with three slashes(\).

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue in JMeter 5.1.  I have JSON that that is embedded in JSON.  Example:

```
{"messages":"{\"outputs\":[\"{\\\"objectstatus\\\":\\\"${__Random(100,200,)}\\\"}\"]}"}
```

What would be posted is this, which is invalid JSON:

```
{"messages":"{\"outputs\":[\"{\\"objectstatus\\":\\"152\\"}\"]}
```

Even if I move all of the functions out of the request body and only use variable substitution, the same thing happens.

The workaround is to "double escape" everything.  Meaning `\" becomes \\"` and `\\\" becomes \\\\\\".`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using the payload in a plain text file and __FileToString() function

[image]

JMeter sends the text data exactly as it is including triple back slashes in appropriate places. I even captured the request using Wireshark sniffer tool to exclude potential issue with the View Results Tree listener

[image]

It might be the case you're suffering from a form of issue which has already been fixed in the latest JMeter release, [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so make sure to upgrade to [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1) or whatever is the latest available version from [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page and you should be able to use parameterisation without any problems.

Comment: As you used __FileToString() function without __eval function, it doesn't resolve the variable value and consider the variable as String. When we use ${__eval($__FileToString().. method it resolve the variable but remove one slash. So the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63255
I added simple JMX test, showing the inconsistent behavior there. 
Jmeter 5.3 still has it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The essential part here is linking the Jmeter defect ID having all the info in plate, to related SO question(s). Don't think Apache's bugzilla would go anywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace \\\ with \\\\\
This worked for me.

Comment: Could you point where this change needs to happen with a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. I have URL encoded request body by using online tool and unchecked the URL Encode check box of parameters in JMeter then replaced correlation and parameterized values with variables. Its worked without any errors.